# Assign groupby mean to column on condition in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Hi suppose I have the df_test as below:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=['bond1','bond1', 'bond2', 'bond2', 'bond3'],
 B=[-1, 1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

I want to create a column C where if B < 0, it's the mean value of B groupby A, if B > 0, it's B. The method I can think of is:

```
group_mean = df_test.groupby('A')['B'].mean().reset_index()
df_merge = df_test.merge(group_mean, on=['A'], how='left')
df_merge['C'] = df_merge.apply(lambda x: x['B_y'] if x['B_x'] <0 else x['B_x'], axis=1)
```

Wondering if it's possible to do it in one line, something like:

```
df_test['C'] = df_test.groupby('B').transform(...)
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df_test['C'] = df_test.groupby('A')['B'].transform('mean').mask(df['B']>0, df_test['B'])
```

Output:

```
       A  B    C
0  bond1 -1  0.0
1  bond1  1  1.0
2  bond2  2  2.5
3  bond2  3  2.5
4  bond3  4  4.0
```

Comment: Thank you! very nice solution